# How do I connect to the Divio postgres database with local PgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, divio

I am trying to connect with PgAdmin to the local Divio database in the container but PgAdmin 4 will not let me connect without a password. The Divio Postgres database seems to come without a password.

Has anyone got round this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a password.

See [Interact with the local database from your host environment](http://docs.divio.com/en/latest/how-to/interact-database.html#from-your-host-environment) in the official documentation.

The key things are:

- expose the database’s port by editing the `docker-compose.yml` file
- use the correct credentials

Both steps are described in more detail in the documentation. I haven't given more specific details here such as port numbers in case those details ever change in the future.